# Does the pointer get assigned first or the incremented?

Tags: c, pointers, increment

When you have the statement:

`*str++ = *end`

Does the `*str` get assigned the value of `*end` or does it get incremented and then get assigned the value of `*end`?

Comment: What would `*(++str) = *end` do?

Comment: @iharob: braces are unnecessary.

Comment: precedence of `++` is higher than the one of `*`, so `*str++` is the same than `*(str++)`.

Comment: Incrementing and decrementing in a bigger expression leads to difficult to find bugs. You should always use multiple lines unless pressing enter causes you physical pain.

Comment: @EOF they don't bother anyone and I think `*++str` is so ugly and unreadable that I would immediately stop reading the rest of the code.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I voted to reopen this because is *not* a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is about  `*p++` or `*(p++)` in general. The question above is about *when* the increment occurs relative to the assignment, which is not addressed in the linked duplicate question. There may be another question in SO that answers this, but it's not that one.

Comment: @lurker Reopened. Then this question is even less useful because it has nothing to do with pointers. It's just the classic pre-vs-post increment question that happens to use a pointer.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart what I find useful about the question is the use of the post increment on the left-hand-side expression. The OP seeks clarity regarding whether the assignment operation occurs before or after *any* left-hand-side increments/decrements. The pointer is the most obvious left-hand-side use case.

Comment: @lurker Valid point. I haven't had my coffee today. But I don't drink coffee so this could be a problem!

Comment: You could see this in any C book you didn't need to ask it here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a **post-increment operator**, it first assigns `*end` then points to new/incremented address of `str`.

Comment: Is this the only post increment operator in C?

Comment: Yes, this is the only post increment operator, not only in c, in c++, java, javascript.

Comment: And also its true about `--` before and after the operand

Comment: @SharanDuggirala it is obviously the only _post increment_ operator in C (why would there be more than one operator for the same thing) but there are other _postfix_ operators such as `[ ]`, `.`, `->`, `--`.

Answer (score 1):

*Logically*, the expression evaluates to something like the following:

```
t0 = str;
t1 = *end;
str = str + 1;
*t0 = t1;
```

except that the exact sequence in which these operations occur is *unspecified*.  The following sequences are also possible:

```
t0 = str;
str = str + 1;
t1 = *end;
*t0 = t1;

t0 = *end;
t1 = str;
*t1 = t0;
str = str + 1;

t0 = *end;
t1 = str;
str = str + 1;
*t1 = t0;
```

The one constant is that we're updating the location that `str` points to *before* the increment.